# More wrong behavior on RSpec expect change count with destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm making an app where people can create jobs, but can only destroy the jobs they've created.  I know that my app lets people destroy jobs because I can test it manually, but RSpec is lagging behind.

Here's the relevant test:

**jobs_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe JobsController do
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:job) { FactoryGirl.create(:job, user: user) }
  let!(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  let!(:wrong_job) { FactoryGirl.create(:job, user: wrong_user) }

  [...]

  describe "correct user control" do
    before { sign_in user }
    describe "users can only delete their own jobs" do
      it "should not change job count" do
        expect do
          delete :destroy, id: wrong_job.id
        end.to_not change(Job, :count)
      end
    end
    describe "users can delete their own jobs" do
      it "should decrease job count" do
        expect do
          delete :destroy, id: job.id
            end.to change(Job, :count).by(-1)
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Here's the failing test:

```
1) JobsController correct user control users can delete their own jobs should decrease job count
     Failure/Error: expect do
       count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/jobs_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_signin, only: [:index, :show]
  skip_before_action :correct_user, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  [...]

  def destroy
    @job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_job
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:title, :org, :internship, :postdate, :filldate, :location, :link, :description)
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :require_signin
  before_filter :correct_user

  include SessionsHelper

  private
    def require_signin
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @job = current_user.jobs.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @job.nil?
    end
end
```

**rake routes**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
       jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)          jobs#index
            POST   /jobs(.:format)          jobs#create
    new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)      jobs#new
   edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format) jobs#edit
        job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#show
            PATCH  /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#update
            PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#update
            DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#destroy
[...]
```

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? Have you gotten past your filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to pass `no_capybara: true` to `sign_in`.  Capybara doesn't work with controller tests, so one can't use capybara to manage the sign in process.

Thanks to Patrick Brinich-Langlois for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Alfvin points out, if there is authentication in controller specs you have to setup a session and pass it as third parameter, for example:

```
...
let(:some_user) { User.create }

def valid_session
  { user_id: some_user.id }
end

describe "DELETE destroy" do
  it "destroys the requested job" do
    job = Job.create! valid_attributes
    expect {
      delete :destroy, { :id => job.to_param }, valid_session
    }.to change(Job, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: +1, although you were generous in your attribution. :-) Actually, I was thinking about this but couldn't find any definitive documentation other than a few SO Q&As. There's nothing about this in the rspec-rails Relish docs. Can you point me to anything?

Comment: You're welcome. Hm, I am definitly not sure if my answer is correct for the question. It is just how I write my controller specs and it comes with Rails scaffold. peterhurford is using a `sign_in` method in a before block. I just had a look at [Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_tests) and it may work...we need more info from peterhurford =)

Comment: The documentation is at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-delete, but it's not clear to me if/why you have to provide additional session parameters in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Why can't I accomplish this using FactoryGirl to make a user and then call "sign_in user"?

Comment: @krabbi: What kind of additional information would you need?

Comment: @peterhurford: We would like to see the `sign_in` method you use. I would recommend you try either Michael Hartls or Rails scaffold approach and continue looking for a best practice that suits your needs...@Peter Alfvin: for example in [this section](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-get) there is mentioned the session parameter

Comment: Using FactoryGirl and using a sign_in method is correct if it works in controller test for example with setting controller.current_user as I understand Michael Hartls approach.

Comment: @Peter Alfvin: better answer to your question is - In the example the JobsController uses a before filter to demand a signed-in user. It is in place for the destroy action. So you have to have a signed in user in the spec that tests that action.

Comment: @krabbi: Here's the sign_in action, in sessions_helper.rb:

`def sign_in(user)
      remember_token = User.new_remember_token
      cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
      user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
      self.current_user = user
    end`

...Formatting the code is difficult.  [Here's the whole thing on GitHub](https://github.com/peterhurford/jobboard/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb).

Comment: Glad you found a solution. But I don't understand it yet =) . Btw the method that you use is [this one](https://github.com/peterhurford/jobboard/blob/master/spec/support/utilities.rb).